# How to overwrtite an file on Google Drive with php?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, overwrite, drive

Anyone who has had anything to do with google files, can you tell me how to overwrite a file?
Now I use this function but, even if the names are the same, it creates another one.

```
function uploadFile($fileName, $folderId, $file) {

    $service = getGoogleDriveService();
    $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
        'name' => $fileName,
        'parents' => array($folderId),
    ));
    try {
        $newFile = $service->files->create(
            $fileMetadata,
            array(
                'data' => file_get_contents($file),
                'mimeType' => mime_content_type($file),
                'uploadType' => 'multipart',
            )
        );
        return $newFile->id;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return 'An error ocurred : ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? [Click first result](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+overwrtite+an+file+on+Google+Drive+with+php%3F)

Comment: Oh, yes, it does! Thank you! I had searched but had not found this page.

Comment: I literally just copied your title in this question and searched on google for it.